# dynamically call data.frame and fill rows

Tags: r, dataframe, assign

I have the following problem:
I am creating a flexible number of data.frames (or matrices would do the job as well) which are filled until the last one, which is not full and should therefore be treated differently
I now want to call the data.frame plate`n` and want to fill it afterwards with data. I would like to do something like

```
assign(paste0("plate", n)[x,y], %some data%)
```

where `[x,y]` is the position in the data.frame(/matrix) and `n` is the n'th data.frame
however it allways gives me

```
incorrect number of dimensions
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. See `?assign`:

> ‘assign’ does not dispatch assignment methods, so **it cannot be
>        used to set elements of vectors**, names, attributes, etc.

(if you can't set elements of vectors you can't do it for dataframes either).

It's probably better to create a *list* of dataframes, rather than manually labelling `plate1`, `plate2` etc. For example, supposing that `plates` was a `list` such that `plates[[1]]` was plate 1, `plates[[2]]` was plate 2, etc:

```
n <- length(plates)
plates[[n]] # is the plateN dataframe
plates[[n]][x, y] <- some_data
```

In terms of constructing the `plates` list, it will depend on your particular example (how you are doing it at the moment), but probably a `for` loop will be helpful here, e.g.:

```
plates <- list()
# supposing you know `n`, the number of plates
for (i in 1:n) {
    plates[[i]] <- code_that_constructs_the_dataframe
}
```

If you're feeling adventurous, `lapply` is quite nice, e.g.

```
# suppose each plate was constructed by reading in a CSV
list_of_csvs <- list.files(pattern='*.csv')
plates <- lapply(list_of_csvs, read.csv)
# then plates[[1]] is the dataframe from the first csv, etc
```

but as you seem new to R, perhaps it is best to stick with the `for` loops for now.

Comment: Thanks mathematical.coffee. I however don't know what the "code_that_constructs_the_data.frame" means. Does it give dimensions to the data.frame? My problem more concrete: I have p permutations that should be aligned in n 6*8 plates. The last one however is only partially filled if (n != multiples of 48). I think that is where a "attempt to set attribute on NULL" error arises when I try to assign data to plates[[i]]

Comment: Ok, figured out what this "code that constructs your data.frame" is:   plates[[p]]<-matrix(ncol = 6,nrow=8, byrow = FALSE)